# unable to load css in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

my all css files placed under `src/assets/css/*` and i am trying to import or load css file inside my component, i have tried to load css with below webpack configuration

Webpack file

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
```

Component

```
import './../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Also tried to load css in index.html file like   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Also, is there a way if i have 5-6 css files by which i dont need to load all files in every component like if we can add in `<head>` tag

Comment: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my webpack.config file. I have used foundation instead of bootstrap but the webpack configuration is similar.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins:[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      './app/components',
      './app/api'
    ],
    alias: {
      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
      actions: 'app/actions/actions.jsx',
      reducers: 'app/reducers/reducers.jsx',
      configureStore: 'app/store/configureStore.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test:/\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  sassLoader:{
    includePaths: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/foundation-sites/scss')
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

And yes you can bundle the css in one file with webpack and import it in the root component.
Check my github repo for more details- https://github.com/hmachaharywork/ReactTodo

Answer (score 0):

Use [Extract text plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage). Only import this plugin in your webpack.conf.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

and refactor your rule like:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: "css-loader"
        })
}
```

Finally, push new instance in plugin list:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
```